# (In R) Merge Directory of CSVs, with some having different number of columns

Tags: r, merge, directory, multiple-columns

I have roughly 50 .csv's with a varying degree of rows and columns. I want to stack the 50 files on top of one another to form one master list. However, I want their columns to match together, with rows missing a value in a missing column filling it with an NA value.

My Code so far:

```
#reads in all my csvs
filelist <- list.files(pattern = ".csv")
list_of_data = lapply(filelist, read.csv)

all_data = do.call(rbind.fill, list_of_data)
write.csv(all_data, file = "all_Data_test.csv")
```

What am I doing wrong? Functionally, do have to read in all the column headers and match based off that?

Thank you

Comment: Actually, I ran into an issue. Getting the error:

    In rbind_all(x, .id) : Unequal factor levels: coercing to character.

So im assuming there may be different data types when columns are matching up. Is there any easy to way to force this?

Comment: It is because some of the columns are `factor`.  I would use `list_of_data <- lapply(filelist, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` to avoid the `character` columns getting converted to `factor`

Comment: @akrun I'm currently getting:

Error: incompatible type (data index: 2, column: 'DP2_HC76', was collecting: integer (dplyr::Collecter_Impl<13>), incompatible with data of type: character.

Any way I can push all the columns through as the same type?

Comment: Looks like similar columns have different class. Check the `str(list_of_data)` and identify same columns having different class and then change it to common type before doingthe `bind_rows`

Comment: Try this `list_of_data2 <- lapply(list_of_data, function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, as.character);x}); all_data <- bind_rows(list_of_data2)`  As we are only writing the full data, we can have all character columns.  Or if we need to change it to different types.  `all_data[] <- lapply(all_data, function(x) type.convert(x))`

Answer (score 0):

One option is `bind_rows` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
all_data <- bind_rows(list_of_data)
```

The output can be written with `write_csv`

```
library(readr)
write_csv(all_data, "all_data_test.csv")
```